# Creating window frame without maximize button and without resizing options?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, window, frame

I need to create a window that acts like "normal" one, but without maximize button, and sizing border.

Searching through Internet, and studying MSDN, I have learned that natively achieving both is impossible.

There is no window style that does both ( I can disable maximize button, but that is not my aim; as for removing resizing options, I have found suitable window styles in the documentation ).

The closest description would be the dialogbox frame behavior ( no sizing border ), but with extra minimize button.

### QUESTION:

Is there a way to achieve my goal some other way?

*If yes, can you please provide links to tutorials or code examples? This would be the first time for me to do such a thing and could use all the help I could get?*

An important note: I have found [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) while searching for a solution, but it will not help me because I target Windows XP onwards.

Answer (score 6):

Creating a window as below will give you a non-sizeable window with a title bar, a minimize button and an exit button.

```
dwStyle = WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
hWnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, szTitle, dwStyle,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,  CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I still need minimize button next to close button :(

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff I edited the answer to include a minimize button.

Comment: I thought I was clear in my post, I do not wish to disable maximize button but to completely remove it -> that is the hard part.

Comment: See the last paragraph of @JaromírAdamec answer.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are creating the window using `CreateWindowEx`. Then, if you omit both `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` and `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` flags (the `dwStyle` parameter), the window will have only the close button (no minimize/maximize) buttons. If you ommit just `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`, Windows draw the maximize box disabled to keep the graphics layout consistent for all windows. There is no way to change this behavior, and it can change in different versions of Windows (Win3.1, for instance, didn't draw the maximize button at all when the flags were set as mentioned.)

Resizable border is disabled by setting other frame than `WS_THICKFRAME` (ie. `WS_BORDER` or `WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME` in the `dwExStyle` parameter).

You can also control the user sizing/moving of your window by intercepting messages `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`, `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`, `WM_SIZING` and `WM_MOVING`.

In theory, you can also completly change the appearance of the non-client area of the window, but it's hardly worth the effort, and it's questionable whether it's a good idea to fight with the default graphic layout of the operating system when all the developers and user are used to it and content with it. (In other words: if you don't want your window to be maximized, just omit the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` flag and leave it on the operating system how to realize this particular decision.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it is documented on MSDN that the window style you want to OMIT is `WS_THICKFRAME`, since the Window Styles page says that a thick frame is a sizing frame.

Comment: Yes, I have found that one. However, this style doesn't remove maximize button...

Comment: You need to ensure that neither `WS_THICKFRAME` nor `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` are included. What window style are you using?

Comment: At the moment I use the following: `WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN` which disables resizing. Now the problem is in maximize box, if I remove `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` maximize button gets disabled. I would have no problem accepting the solution where I create my own button in the frame and program minimizing/restoring of the window of my own ( this would be my first time but one has to learn all the time I guess... ). I just want to be sure that I will cover all the cases, like pressing the button, ALT+TAB, clicking on system menu etc...